# eclipse: import (classname) cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new in using eclipse java using multiple `.java` files. My eclipse java project consist of one project file two package files, each with one `.java` class

My 2nd java class import the 1st java class/package, like so

### VerifyLogin.java

```
package VerifyLogin;
import ArgumentCountException;
```

### ArgumentCountException.java

```
// ...
```

The problem is `VerifyLogin.java` is getting an error

> Import ArgumentCountException cannot be resolved

Or any reference I have to `ArgumentCountException` cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Isn't this `ArgumentCountException` should be `import YourPackageName.ArgumentCountException`

Comment: Can you show us a little tree of you project structure?

Comment: Also note that package names should be lowercase (by convention)

Comment: Use CTRL + Shift + O keyboard shortcut in eclipse to organize your imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java if you need to import a class then you need to use the full qualified name for that class, as the following:

```
import packageName.YourClass;
```

For Example, if your need to use `Scanner` class, then you need to import it as:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

But if the class was withing the same package, you don't need to import it.

Answer (score 0):

When importing your class, it should be done as below:

```
//Current package name for the VerifyLogin Class (All package names should be lowercase by convention)
package packageforcurrentclass;

//Import statements: import thedependencyclasspackage.thedependencyclassname
import exceptionpackage.ArgumentCountException;

public class VerifyLogin 
{
...
}
```

Comment: I made my package name the same as my .java file that is why I thought I was importing it correctly. 
Now I have import ArgumentClassException.ArgumentClassException; and it works. 
Thank you all.

Comment: You should at least accept one answer and maybe upvote the one that helped figuring out the problem, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack overflow. I checked one now, I think that auto saves it.